# Merge sort Process Explain (top down , bottom up)

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

What will be the merge sort process steps for elements :
**20 47 15 8 9 4 40 30 12 17**

I have come across this ...

> **Pass1:** |20 47|   |8 15|   |4 9|   |30 40|   |12 17|
>
> **Pass2:** |8 15 20 47|    |4 9 30 40|    |12 17|

now the confusion is what will be Pass3 and Pass4? (combining quads or pair+quad in Pass3) also, is this top down or bottom up approach?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaqR3G_NVoo maybe this could help you to fully understand how the passes are (I'm not trolling, I found it quite good for learning lol)

Comment: You are using a bottom-up approach, doubling the merge length at each iteration, so pass3: |4 8 9 15 20 30 40 47| |12 17|; pass4: |4 8 9 12 15 17 20 30 40 47|. There is also a top-down approach, where you split the list in half, recursively sort each half, then merge the two halves.

Comment: @IanAbbott what are they using in this example? http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/

Comment: [geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/) is using a top-down merge sort.

Comment: @IanAbbott in the link why are they sorting and merging on the same level if it is a recursive approach? should they not sort and merge left part first and then right and finally merge left and right?

Comment: @ashish That's exactly what the `mergeSort` function in the link does. It sorts and merges the left part using `mergeSort`, then sorts and merges the right part using `mergeSort`, then finally merges the left and right parts using `merge`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the passes for a bottom up merge sort. The array of 10 elements is treated as 10 sub-arrays of 1 element each, sorted because there is only 1 element per sub array. There are n-1 merge operations (n/2+n/4+n/8+...).

```
 20 47 15  8  9  4 40 30 12 17    initial array 
|20|47|15| 8| 9| 4|40|30|12|17|   consider as 10 sub arrays of size 1
|20 47| 8 15| 4  9|30 40|12 17|   pass 1, 5 merges
| 8 15 20 47| 4  9 30 40|12 17|   pass 2, 2 merges
| 4  8  9 15 20 30 40 47|12 17|   pass 3, 1 merge
| 4  8  9 12 15 17 20 30 40 47|   pass 4, 1 merge
```

Wiki article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation

Note that although most classroom type merge sorts are top down, most actual libraries use some variation of bottom up merge sort.

This would be the order of operations for top down merge sort, which is depth first, left first. Assuming an optimized top down merge sort that uses indexing to split sub-arrays, n-1 pairs of indices are generated and stored on the stack due to the recursive splitting of sub-arrays, corresponding to n-1 merge operations that occur with a typical 2 way merge sort. Note that merging does not begin until the first instance where two sub-arrays of size 1 are created via the recursive splitting. Then splitting and merging continue down and up the call stack, depth first, left first.

For the 10 elements in this example, there are 10-1=9 split and merge operations.

```
 20 47 15  8  9  4 40 30 12 17 
|20 47 15  8  9| 4 40 30 12 17|  lvl 0 split
|20 47|15  8  9|                 lvl 1 split
|20|47|                          lvl 2 split
|20|                             lvl 3 size == 1
   |47|                          lvl 3 size == 1
|20 47|                          lvl 2 merge
      |15| 8  9|                 lvl 2 split
      |15|                       lvl 3 size == 1
         | 8| 9|                 lvl 3 split
         | 8|                    lvl 4 size == 1
            | 9|                 lvl 4 size == 1
         | 8  9|                 lvl 3 merge
      | 8  9 15|                 lvl 2 merge
| 8  9 15 20 47|                 lvl 1 merge
               | 4 40|30 12 17|  lvl 1 split
               | 4|40|           lvl 2 split
               | 4|              lvl 3 size == 1
                  |40|           lvl 3 size == 1
               | 4 40|           lvl 2 merge
                     |30|12 17|  lvl 2 split
                     |30|        lvl 3 size == 1
                        |12|17|  lvl 3 split
                        |12|     lvl 4 size == 1
                           |17|  lvl 4 size == 1
                        |12 17|  lvl 3 merge
                     |12 17 30|  lvl 2 merge
               | 4 12 17 30 40|  lvl 1 merge
| 4  8  9 12 15 17 20 30 40 47|  lvl 0 merge
```

Bottom up merge sort skips all the recursive splitting by treating an array of n elements as n sub-arrays of 1 element each, and immediately starts the merge process, generating indices as needed via iteration. For large arrays, most of the time is spent merging, which is the same for both top down and bottom up, in which case top down isn't that much slower than bottom up, but most libraries will implement some variation of bottom up merge sort for sorts like std::stable_sort.

Comment: please, can u write the passes for top down for the same question!

Comment: @ashish - Top down doesn't have `passes`, instead there are levels of recursion and an ordering of operations that is depth first, left first.

Comment: @ashish - in a typical top down merge sort, when splitting an odd number of elements, the left "half" is one less element than the right "half, so 5 is split in to 2:3, and 3 is split into 1:2. So the sequence is {5} -> {{2}:{3}} -> {{2}:{{1}:{2}}} .